# Python coverage does not see config file

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, coverage.py

I am running python coverage for Django unit tests in parallel mode:

```
coverage run --source='.' --concurrency=multiprocessing manage.py test --parallel
```

It is complaining: `Options affecting multiprocessing must be specified in a configuration file.`

But I have `.coveragerc` file in the same directory from which I start coverage with the following content:

```
[run]
branch = True
concurrency = multiprocessing
```

Tried to specify `--rcfile` option for coverage run, that did not help. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not provide the `--concurrency` parameter as a command line argument, but in the config file only.

Comment: I just changed the message to, "Options affecting multiprocessing must only be specified in a configuration file."  Would that have been clearer? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Thank you Ned, to me it's clearer, though I am not native English speaker. Maybe, also add "please remove them from command line parameters"

Comment: Looking at this a little more, it's not --concurrency that had to be removed from the command line, it was --source.  I've changed the message again.  Now it will say, "Options affecting multiprocessing must only be specified in a configuration file. Remove --source from the command line."